# PHP Google Pub/Sub: Why 404 (not found) error when calling listTopics?

Tags: php, google-cloud-pubsub

I've got a PHP script using an old Pubsub PHP API (I can't replace it). When I try to list topics, I get an exception:

```
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/pubsub/v1beta1/topics: (404) Not Found
```

The code is:

```
$pubsub_service = new Google_Service_Pubsub($client);
$topicListResponse = $pubsub_service->topics->listTopics();
```

Any ideas what's going on?
Worth mentioning the Google Client I'm using seems to work in other parts of the project, where it allows me to access some BigQuery resources, so I don't think there is some generic issue with the client itself (unless it's a permission issue, in which case I couldn't find how to explicitly allow a service account to list topics)

Comment: Looks like you are using a decrepated API. https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/

Comment: I realize that, however, as I mentioned, that API (at least its BigQuery part) works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v1beta1 version was deprecated some time ago and no longer works (v1 has been the version used by the client libraries for a few years now). Every product has their own versioning/deprecation schedule for older APIs and so it is entirely possible BigQuery endpoints have not changed since the time the library you are using was written. In order to continue using Pub/Sub, you will have to update to a newer version of the library that doesn't use a deprecated version.